# Cannot understand/ reproduce reuslt in figure 1 from MobileNetV2?

Tags: deep-learning

Hi I am recently reading the MobileNetV2 paper and I found I cannot understand the following figure in the paper.
[image]

I made a simple code trying to reproduce the results, but I got opposite results.
These are visualizations of (1)my input, (2)after ReLU in 3 dimensional space, (3)transform from 3D back to 2D:

[image][image][image]

And here is the result for transforming the same input to 15 dimensional space, applying ReLU and transform back to 2D.

[image]

I don't see an obvious difference as expected in the paper. Since this paper is cited many times, I bet I made mistakes somewhere. Could anybody help point out where I am wrong? I used the following code to generate my results:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n=256
angle = np.linspace(0, 12*2*np.pi, n)
radius = np.linspace(.5, 1., n)
x = radius * np.cos(angle)
y = radius * np.sin(angle)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

# ==== embed into 3 dimensional space and transform back after applying ReLU ====
T = np.random.random((3, 2))
T_inv = np.linalg.pinv(T)
after_T = T @ np.row_stack((x, y))
after_relu = after_T
after_relu[after_relu < 0] = 0

# ---- visualize transformed 3d shape ----
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(after_relu[0],after_relu[1],after_relu[2])
plt.show()
# ---- ----

new_x_y = T_inv @ after_relu
plt.plot(new_x_y[0], new_x_y[1])
plt.show()


# ==== embed into 15 dimensional space and transform back after applying ReLU ====
T = np.random.random((15, 2))
T_inv = np.linalg.pinv(T)
after_T = T @ np.row_stack((x, y))
after_relu = after_T
after_relu[after_relu < 0] = 0
new_x_y = T_inv @ after_relu
plt.plot(new_x_y[0], new_x_y[1])
plt.show()
```